# Scrapy: How to get address using CSS and XPath?

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

How to get address using CSS and XPath? I tried to use CSS: `response.css('.office-address::text').extract()`

```html
<span class="office-address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <span itemprop="streetAddress">
                    <span class="address-line1">5835 Post Rd.</span>

                        <span class="address-line2">Suite 217</span>
                </span>
                <span class="city-state-zip">
                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">East Greenwich</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">RI</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">02818</span>
                </span>
            </span>
```

Comment: Try this `address = ' '.join([i.strip() for i in response.css('.office-address span::text').getall()])` . It should work in the csv as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `response.css('.office-address ::text').extract()` Added space before `::text`

Comment: it works in scrapy shell, but not in the csv
`yield {
        ...
        'Address': response.css('.office-address ::text').extract(),
        ...                
       }`

Answer (score 2):

Dirty solution with a one liner XPath :

```
concat(//span[@class='address-line1']/text(),' ',//span[@class='address-line2']/text(),' ',//span[@itemprop='addressLocality']/text(),', ',//span[@itemprop='addressRegion']/text(),//span[@itemprop='postalCode']/text())
```

Output :

```
"5835 Post Rd. Suite 217 East Greenwich, RI02818"
```

Comment: Or even simpler `string-join(//span//text(),' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Option with CSS selectors with scrapy:

```
address = response.css("span.address-line1::text, span.address-line2::text, span[itemprop=addressLocality]::text, span[itemprop=addressRegion]::text, span[itemprop=postalCode]::text").extract() # should return list
if address:
    address = ", ".
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is future-proof idea since ids/classes can change over the period:

```
from re import sub
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

teststr = """<span class="office-address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <span itemprop="streetAddress">
                    <span class="address-line1">5835 Post Rd.</span>

                        <span class="address-line2">Suite 217</span>
                </span>
                <span class="city-state-zip">
                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">East Greenwich</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">RI</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">02818</span>
                </span>
            </span>"""

r = bs(teststr,"lxml").getText().strip()
r = sub( r"\n", ", ", r)
r = sub( r"[, ]{2,}", ", ", r)
print ( r )
```

Result:

```
5835 Post Rd., Suite 217, East Greenwich, RI 02818
```